# Differences between versions of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client libraries - ComboTree.SetSelectedText(System.String) is missing

Tags: c#, tfs, libraries, azure-pipelines

I have an issue with my code that connect to TFS/VSTS and writes work items from it.

```
public FormSearchWorkItems(WorkItemStore workItemStore, string projectName)
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         WorkingItem = new WorkingItem();

         pickWorkItemsControl = new PickWorkItemsControl(workItemStore, false);
    }
```

It worked well with TFS using old version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client (12.0.0.0), but after an update to the newest Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client (15.0.0.0), there is an expection for PickWorkItemsControl throwed:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll

Additional information: Method not found: Void Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ComboTree.SetSelectedText(System.String).

So the problem is that there is missing SetSelectedText(System.string) method in the newest version of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

Does anyone know the workaround of this problem please?

Comment: There isn't PickWorkItemsControl class in 15.0 TFS assemblies. How do you use it? Do you remove old assemblies? On the other hand, it is UserControl of windows form that you can achieve it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The method Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ComboTree.SetSelectedText is not exist in the 15.0.0 version.

You can install latest version of [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package, and then build again. This package contains all the reference you used. And you can develop the similar method by yourself.

> Integrate with Microsoft Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Team
>   Services from desktop-based Windows applications. Work with and manage
>   version control, work items, and build, and other resources from your
>   client application.

Comment: Unfortunately these assemblies are from the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient package. 
When i checked methods using JustDecompile, in the latest Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client the method SetSelectedText(String) is not in the ComboTree but in the CustomCombo<T>.
So problem is that the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll is obsolete (v 12.0.0.0) and i dont know alternative of it.

Comment: I updated my answer, and the method does not exist in version 15.0. Sorry for the typo.